# How do I include knockout viewmodel defined in separate javascript file in my view?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to using knockout and I have created a view model that was originally in my view which worked and updated the text as I entered into the textbox but after I moved the knockout viewmodel from my view into a separate javasctipt file and included it in the view referencing it in the script tags the knockout bindings are not applied. What else do I need to do? How do I get this to work? I don't want to have script tags in every view referencing knockout and having the view models defined in the view, I want the view models in separate files.

**Here is my view model** which worked when I include it within script tags in my view. I have moved it to a separate file called `UserDashboardViewModel.js` and including it in my view but it does not work when in a separate file, only when included in the view:

```
var viewModel = {
    monkey: ko.observable(),
    array: ko.observableArray(),
    AddAnimal: function () 
    {
        this.array.push(this.monkey());
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**And in my view:**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/UserDashboardViewModel.js></script>

<h1 data-bind="text: monkey">text</h1>
... other knockout data-bindings that do not work
```

Comment: Here the browser will download both scripts in parallel and execute them as soon as possible, maintaining their order.Load knockout lib on your layout base then whenever you load a View Model.js you are sure `knockout` got loaded before.

Comment: Try to move your script tags at the end of the body. The view has to be loaded before the applyBindings method has been called.

Comment: Why you couldn't use `window.onload` function for casting `ko.applyBindings` in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your script tags are in the `head` of your `HTML` page then you need to make sure you call `ko.applyBindings()` when the DOM is loaded.

```
// with jQuery 
$(document).ready(function(){ko.applyBindings(viewModel); });

// shorter jQuery version 
$(function(){ ko.applyBindings(viewModel); });

// without jQuery (doesn't work in older IEs)
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}, false);
```